# merge multiple arrays from foreach loop into one array

Tags: php

Here is the code I am using to run through the loop and return the values

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $certs) {

$x509 = new File_X509();
$chain = $x509->loadX509($certs);
$ICN = $x509->getIssuerDNProp('CN');

print_r($ICN);
}
```

I am using an external library to parse `$certs` and finally end up with `$ICN` which has the final value i am interested in. However, each value is in its own array, I would like to merge them together into one array.

Here is the current output for `$print_r($ICN)`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => thawte DV SSL CA - G2
)
Array
(
    [0] => thawte Primary Root CA
)
Array
(
    [0] => Thawte Premium Server CA
)
```

Here is the desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => thawte DV SSL CA - G2
    [1] => thawte Primary Root CA
    [2] => Thawte Premium Server CA
)
```

-- ATTEMPT --

Using the following code offered by @zeflex

```
$finalArray = array();

foreach ($matches[0] as $certs) {

    $x509 = new File_X509();
    $chain = $x509->loadX509($certs);
    $ICN = $x509->getIssuerDNProp('CN');
    $finalArray[] = $ICN[0];

}

print_r($finalArray);
```

Resulted in this output - as you can see, only the last value is in the array - the first two not included for some reason??

```
Array
(
    [0] => Thawte Premium Server CA
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$finalArray = array(); 
foreach($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate_chain"] as $chain) { 
openssl_x509_export($chain, $pemchain); 
//echo $pem_chain; 
$str = $pemchain; // The certificates string 
preg_match_all('/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----[^-]*-----END CERTIFICATE-----/s', $str, $pems); 
//print_r($matches[0]); // $matches[1] is an array that contains every certificate string 

foreach ($pems[0] as $key => $certs) { 
$x509 = new File_X509(); 
$chain = $x509->loadX509($certs); 
$ICN = $x509->getIssuerDNProp('CN'); 


foreach($ICN AS $k => $v) { 
$finalArray[] = $v; 
} 

} 
} 
print_r($finalArray);
```

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eeb86e33626f92f83ad317772e2d63fa80b84f22 check this code, it's similar than yours excepts if I missed something.

Comment: yes, that code works but its not the same as what i need. I am using external library to parse data which then create the arrays `$ICN`, I need to merge each instance of `$ICN` in the interation

Comment: just thinking out loud, is another way to do this by saving the data $ICN for each iteration of the loop then merge them?

Comment: i updated my post to show you the results of your original solution but as you can see, only one value ended up in the array and not all three of them ?

Comment: I've update my code. If it's still not working, do a `var_dump($matches[0])` before the foreach loop and post the result to investigate.

Comment: yeah, still only showing one value.. here is the full code http://www.pastebin.ca/3005297 and here is the output of var_dump http://www.pastebin.ca/3005298

Comment: just noticed there was a bit of code missing from the one i gave you here is the full one: http://www.pastebin.ca/3005301

Comment: still no go. can we chat? here is the output of your code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0fdbeaecb1c8e8897f63c962206f1eade4455796

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78144/discussion-between-user3436467-and-zeflex).